# Automatically populating one database table from another. Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, api

We are using Devise in a rails API and have a users table that includes NAME and EMAIL and the other usual sign-up information. We also have a Tutor profile table with a one_to_one relationship to users. What we want is that when a new user signs up, NAME and EMAIL from the individual users record automatically populates their Tutor profile table as a default value. Here are our rails models. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!! :-)

```
class Tutor < ApplicationRecord
  # delegate :email, :email=, to: :user
  after_initialize :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.image_url ||= "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1378/PNG/512/avatardefault_92824.png"
    self.bio ||= ""
  end

  belongs_to :user
end


class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :tutor#, dependent: :destory
  after_create :init_tutor
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :tutor
  # delegate :email, :email=, to: :tutor

  def init_tutor
    self.create_tutor
  end

  def generate_jwt
    JWT.encode({ id: id,
                exp: 60.days.from_now.to_i },
               Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
  end
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

        # validates :fullname uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true  #, allow_blank: false, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/ }
end
```

Comment: it looks as if you tried `delegate :email, :email=, to: :user` in the Tutor model. This is the right way to do it. Didn't it work?  try putting `belongs_to :user` before the delegate statement.

Comment: Do your want to use the user's name and email as a fallback when there is not specific tutor name and email set? Or should both values always be the same?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*NOTE: Having identical fields with identical data as requested is generally considered bad database design. You can fairly easily lookup the user's name and email address from the tutor object (e.g. delegating the methods) and use a join when doing queries. If that works for your application it is a far better approach than copying the data as suggested below.*

You can create a tutor with the same name and email as the user with the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :tutor, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :init_tutor

  def init_tutor
    create_tutor(email: email, name: name)
  end
```

However, I would generally recommend against using `before` or `after` hooks in active-record that have any impact outside of that record (for example, creating a different record, sending an email, etc). Having done things like this in larger applications my experience has been that, over time, this path leads to madness. It means that creating or updating objects may create or update other objects which may create or update other objects or have other side effects, making it very difficult to understand or anticipate what saving a record might do.

Instead I'd recommend using a [ServiceObject](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) pattern (or similar). This would look something like:

```
class UserCreator
  def call(user_params)
    user = User.create(params)
    user.create_tutor(params.slice(:name, :email))
    user
  end
end
```

This pattern gets better as your application grows and you need a place to do things like send an email, enqueue a background job, update a users-count, whatever.

Comment: it's a really bad idea to do as the OP requested, duplicate records from one table into another. It's bad database design practice to duplicate information. The methods demonstrated in this response have many ways for the tables to become unsynchronized. Please don't do it!

Comment: Totally agree that it's a bad practice to duplicate data across tables, the solution is suggested since that's what was what is being asked. Will update the solution w/ a suggestion not to do it.